# Mean running time over a number of runs

Tags: bash

I would like to report the mean running time (computed using the [time command](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_time.htm)) of a script after running it, say, *n* times. Is there a simple `bash` command, script, or system utility that I'm unaware of and that would allow me to do that?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/603897/how-to-measure-average-execution-time-of-a-script

Answer (score 11):

This is an interesting question [so I took a few minute and wrote a script for it](http://blog.hozbox.com/2011/11/22/average-time-for-running-a-command-plus-20-other-averages/).  Below is the *light* version of the script which takes in a file that has the output of running the `time` command.  [The full script](http://blog.hozbox.com/2011/11/22/average-time-for-running-a-command-plus-20-other-averages/) has many more options and takes in a command directly to run averages on directly.

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# calculate the mean average of wall clock time from multiple /usr/bin/time results.

file=${1}
cnt=0

if [ ${#file} -lt 1 ]; then
    echo "you must specify a file containing output of /usr/bin/time results"
    exit 1
elif [ ${#file} -gt 1 ]; then
    samples=(`grep --color=never  real ${file} | awk '{print $2}' | cut -dm -f2 | cut -ds -f1`)

    for sample in `grep --color=never real ${file} | awk '{print $2}' | cut -dm -f2 | cut -ds -f1`; do
        cnt=$(echo ${cnt}+${sample} | bc -l)
    done

    # Calculate the 'Mean' average (sum / samples).
    mean_avg=$(echo ${cnt}/${#samples[@]} | bc -l)
    mean_avg=$(echo ${mean_avg} | cut -b1-6)

    printf "\tSamples:\t%s \n\tMean Avg:\t%s\n\n" ${#samples[@]} ${mean_avg}
fi
```

Example (here I named the script `timeit.sh` and `chmod 775 timeit.sh` and `chown jon timeit.sh`*):

```
[ 09:22 jon@hozbox.com ~ ]$ /usr/bin/time -a -o times.log -p sleep 3
[ 09:23 jon@hozbox.com ~ ]$ /usr/bin/time -a -o times.log -p sleep 1
[ 09:23 jon@hozbox.com ~ ]$ /usr/bin/time -a -o times.log -p sleep 2
[ 09:23 jon@hozbox.com ~ ]$ /usr/bin/time -a -o times.log -p sleep 2
[ 09:23 jon@hozbox.com ~ ]$ /usr/bin/time -a -o times.log -p sleep 7
[ 09:23 jon@hozbox.com ~ ]$ /usr/bin/time -a -o times.log -p sleep 0.5
[ 09:23 jon@hozbox.com ~ ]$ ./timeit.sh times.log
        Samples:        6
        Mean Avg:       2.5833

[ 09:23 jon@hozbox.com ~ ]$ cat times.log
real 3.00
user 0.00
sys 0.00
real 1.00
user 0.00
sys 0.00
real 2.00
user 0.00
sys 0.00
real 2.00
user 0.00
sys 0.00
real 7.00
user 0.00
sys 0.00
real 0.50
user 0.00
sys 0.00
```

---

*`chown` isnt necessary here, but I couldn't help it! :)

[`man time`](http://ss64.com/bash/time.html):

> Syntax
>   `time [option...] command [arg...]`
>
> Options
>
> `-o FILE  --output=FILE`
>    Write the resource use statistics to FILE.
>
> `-a  --append`
>    *Append* the resource use information to the output file instead
>     of overwriting it.
>
> `-o FILE  --output=FILE`
>    Write the resource use statistics to FILE.  By default, this
>    *overwrites* the file, destroying the file's previous contents.
>
> `-p  --portability`
>    Use the POSIX format.

Comment: I really love this.

Answer (score 2):

I was asking here about something similar: [Average Execution Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764820/average-execution-time). The advice was to use [Dumbbench](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Dumbbench/), a Perl script that runs the software several times and prints out some statistics.

Answer (score 0):

There's no one single command that could do this. What you can do is append the times from each run into a file, and the calculate the mean from those numbers.

Answer (score 0):

**A)**
This seems to be working to execute command/script 10 times and output total execution time which can then be divided by number of executions in order to get the mean execution time:

```
time (for i in {1..10}; do sleep 0; /path/to/script 1>/dev/null; done)
```

`1..10` executes the command 10 times

`1>/dev/null` prevents standard output of the /path/to/script

`sleep 0` does not sleep/delay between the script executions

**B)**
Alternative way is to install package named `multitime`, on Debian/Ubuntu: `apt install multitime`. And run: `multitime -n 10 -s 0 -q /path/to/script`

`-n 10` executes the command 10 times

`-s 0` does not sleep/delay between the script executions

`-q` keep quiet, suppresses stdout output

**C)**
[Hyperfine utility](https://github.com/sharkdp/hyperfine?tab=readme-ov-file#hyperfine) to also compare two commands/scripts runtime.